# Sending minor correction to a journal before getting a copy for proofread

Tags: formatting, proofreading

Recently the European Journal of Physics accepted my paper. Right now I'm waiting for them to send me a final copy for proofreading. Today I was just going through the revised manuscript and spotted a  minor typo in an equation. As in, it should have been \tan ^{-1}(ab) rather than \tan (ab). It might have missed the reviewer and my eyes back to back. 
Should I inform the journal about this minor mistake now or wait for them to give me a copy for proofreading?

Answer (score 4):

Include this change when you correct the proofs.  It'll be easier for the copy editor to make all the changes at once.